# Why my dataset is not accessible in the button click event c#

Tags: c#, events, datatable, dataset

I have a Windows Form in VS2013 C#. I have this in the Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // ...
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Legend");
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet("Graph");
        DataRow dRow;
        dSet.Tables.Add("Legend");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Unit");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Val");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
    }
```

This part works fine, the table on the form is filled with the column headers.
Then I want to add Rows to the table in a button click event:

```
private void btnAddSeries_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow newEntry = dt1.NewRow();
    newEntry["Name"] = "Pressure";
    newEntry["Unit"] = "bar";
    newEntry["Val"] = 12;
    dt1.Rows.Add(newEntry);
}
```

What am I missing, I get the error "The name 'dt1' does not exist in the current context"

Appreciate any help

Comment: Because you created `dt1` inside your Form constructor, It will only be available there. You have to define it at class level to access it in multiple methods.

Comment: Does this class have to be static? I want to always use the same table for other events as well.

Comment: `Franl Meier` look up this in your spare time 
[Access Modifiers C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: I know that, but it seems I did not understand. My class is static, so only one instance is available, and now I use a property: public static DataTable dt1 {get;set;}. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

As per Habib, when you declare it in the Form1 constructor, it becomes local variable. You should define it at the top of the Form1 class (outside the constructor) so that is a global variable.

Comment: on top of the 'public Form1()' is only the 'public partial class Form1: Form' and on top of that is the 'namespace MyProgramName'. If I put this anywhere on top of the Form1 it does not work at all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out with the help of the singleton pattern, though I am not sure whether this really is a singleton:

Adding this class:

```
public sealed class ChartDataTable
{
    static readonly DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    public static DataTable Gdt1
    {
        get{
            return dt1;
           }
    }

}
```

This works great, I can do whatever I want to my table e.g.:

```
ChartDataTable.Gdt1.Rows.Add(items here);
```

It updates automatically in the datagridview on the form.